# What is the correct layout for this structure?

Tags: android

What is the structure of such a layout? The text in the left column aligned to the right, the text of right column aligned to the left. Also rows are separated with a line. Thank you for hints!

[image]

Comment: seems to be a table rows or listview with two elements populated

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could make a `ListView` of your own items. That would give you a separator between all rows.

To set your own layout for `ListView`'s item, you have to prepare your layout's xml file and set it like this:

```
yourListView.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.layout_file_for_your_item, items));
```

`Item`'s layout (`LinearLayout`) could consist of 2 `LinearLayout`s. In first one (left) you'd have `TextView` that would be aligned right in parent. Second one (right) would have `TextView` aligned left in parent and margin-left set to some specific value to make a gap between two layouts.

[image]

1. Blue: ListView
2. Red:  ListView's item (LinearLayout)
3. Green: First LinearLayout
4. Yellow: Second LinearLayout

Comment: @IlyaDemidov Because if you have only TextView, you don't know how far should you move it. In LinearLayout's case, you just have to specify it's width and make TextView to be aligned left and that fixes a problem. So basically what you have to set is layouts widths and a gap between them. Parent for them may also be a LinearLayout.

Answer (score 0):

You can try create listview field in your layout (with empty inside, not textviews or images) and then create another layout something like that:

Main layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="bla bla" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="bla bla 2" />

    <!-- listview with populated items -->

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/mylist"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
    </ListView>

</LinearLayout>
```

Populated items:

```
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/itemleft"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:gravity="right|center_vertical"
        android:text="Location" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/itemright"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="left|center_vertical"
        android:text="Los Angeles, US" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Here is a preview of this settings:
[image]
There is of course only one item but it will be populated then. It's just a preview.

(Populated items will be used in listView later) Then try use for example base adapter implementation in you code, check here example: [link](http://android-helper.blogspot.com/2011/07/android-custom-listview-example.html). I hope you will understand it, however using custom listview wasn't the problem in this title :)